# laravel 4: how to subtract one from current value of column when updating rows?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I was wondering how to perform something like this:

```
Table::update(array('position'=>'position+1'));
```

As far as I know, laravel 4 handles 'position+1' as a string, thus is becomes 0.

I want to perform something like

```
UPDATE table SET position = position + 1
```

Can I do that using eloquent?

EDIT: nevermind, doh.."DB::table('users')->increment('votes');"

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Simply make use of the `increment` method:

```
DB::table('users')->increment('position');
```

The same is valid for `decrement`:

```
DB::table('users')->decrement('rank');
```

You may even set the second parameter to the amount you want to add/subtract:

```
DB::table('users')->increment('posts', 5);
DB::table('users')->decrement('likes', 3);
```

Also, if you need to update other columns along with it, you pass it as the third parameter:

```
DB::table('users')->increment('range', 3, array(
    'name' => 'Raphael',
    'rank' => 10
));
```

And the same goes for `Eloquent` models, as well:

```
$firstUser = User::find(1);
$firstUser->increment('height', 0.1, array(
    'active' => false
));
```

Comment: I got something to ask, what if i want to check the result after the increament or decreament? Like check the result is 0 or negative?

Comment: @Ben Why not check before the increment? Just adjust the logic?

Comment: @rmobis here is the reason, because after i increase the number only can know is that exceed the number of stock, if exist then cannot be purchase.. Thats why i have to increase first then check, but sure your login is correct, just i not sure how to get the number out from the database and do the comparison..:)

Comment: @Ben Dude, that makes no sense. Say you have `x` and you increment it by 1. Now you wanna check if `x > y`. This is the same as to check if `x + 1 > y` before incrementing. Which is the correct logic.

Answer (score 8):

you can also do with DB::raw method like this:

```
DB::table('tablename')->where(your condition)->update(['position' => DB::raw('position+1')]);
```

you can also do other operations with this like

```
DB::table('tablename')->where(your condition)->update(['position' => DB::raw('position * 2')]);
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked fine for me

```
\Models\User::where("id", $userId)->increment("points");
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Well my answer builds on top of the answer already given for those looking for incrementing a single record. It generate this query UPDATE table SET position = position + 1 Where id = 1

Answer (score -2):

simply you can use the DB::raw method like this：
`Table::update(DB::raw('position=position+1'));`