# laravel: how to multiply current value of column with some value when updating rows?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

## Problem:

I want to update two column of mysql table,

**`column1` decrement with some value and `column2` multiplication with some value,**

I have done about decrement like this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307202/laravel-4-how-to-subtract-one-from-current-value-of-column-when-updating-rows)

## Tried:

```
$stock_obj->decrement('quantity_on_hand', $product_data["quantity"], array(
    'total_quantity_on_hand' => 'quantity_on_hand' * some_other_value
));
```

Here decrement working but how can i do multiplication?

I have that solution in CI(CodeIgniter) but don't know how to does it in laravel any help would be appreciated...

## CI(CodeIgniter) WAY:

```
$this->db->set("quantity_on_hand", "quantity_on_hand-" . ($product_data["quantity"] ? $product_data["quantity"] : 0), FALSE);
$this->db->set("total_quantity_on_hand", "quantity_on_hand*" . ($product_data['product_packing_value'] ? $product_data['product_packing_value'] : 1), FALSE);
$this->db->where("id", $warehouse_transfer_product_data['stock_id'])->update("stock");
```

Comment: is it you want the column2 to be (2*column1)?

Comment: @Rafiq `column1 = column1 - 'dynamic_value' `and `column2 = column1 * 'some_other_value'`

Comment: Nliyapra are you using mysql.?

Comment: @Rafiq yes with laravel eloquent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
DB::table('your_table')
->where('some_column', $someValue)
->update(array(
    'column1' => DB::raw('column1 * 2'),
    'column2' => DB::raw('column2 - 1'),
));
```

Comment: then what about `decrement` i want both together `multiplication` and `decrement`

Comment: You can just add another column, I'l updating the answer

Comment: Working but what if now i want to put where condition with this query

Comment: Just add the where condition the same way you'd do this anywhere else. I'll update the answer